# mysql count function not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get a count of product-page views that happened 1 day before purchased. I used this query

```
SELECT 
    p.customer_id AS cid,
    p.product_id AS product,
    p.revenue,
    p.order_id,
    p.datetime,
    pv.customer_id,
    pv.product_id,
    pv.datetime AS date,
    od.name2,
    COUNT(pv.product_id)
FROM
    customer_profiles.purchase p
        LEFT JOIN
    customer_profiles.product_view pv ON pv.customer_id = p.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN
    opencart.product_description od ON od.product_id = p.product_id
        AND od.language_id = 2
WHERE
    pv.datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(p.datetime),
        INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE(p.datetime)
        AND pv.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY pv.product_id
```

but count is not work properly its give a randomly number. I already used  count(DISTINCT pv.product_id) unfortunately it also doesn't work for me?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: You must have every single item in the select list as part of an aggregate function or in the group by.  You can't group by a single column when there is more than one corresponding value in other columns.

Comment: @EvanCallahan do you have any alternative solution for this one?

Comment: @jarlh than what i used instead of group by?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just include all of the columns you are using in the group by or make the above query into a temp table and then pull the counts from there.

Comment: @EvanCallahan thank you its worked. i just group by first four column n its give me the answer what i want..